# Optimal way to set and read variables

Tags: environment-variables, services, arch-arm

I need to set 6 variables which are used by several services and applications in Linux. I have so far been using the environment variables, but find it very complicating to modify these variables throughout multiple users. At the same time I wish that all users are able to modify these variables that are used globally.

My solution so far has been to use SQLite instead, but seems to be a bit of a mess when I want to set the variables within a service daemon.

So the question is, is it possible or even realistic to use global environment variables that can be altered by any user or should I consider a database solution such as SQLite?

E.g. if i have a variable `IP_RECIPIENT`, this variable has to be accessed and set by all users in the system. If it is altered, all users should be able to read the changes, in other words it has to be global even when altered and not just local.

Also whats the best-practice for using global environment variables within Arch Linux ARM.

Comment: Please [edit] and explain what these variables do in a bit more detail. From what I can understand, simply defining them in `/etc/profile` would be enough. They would then be available to all users and they would be free to modify them for their own sessions.

Comment: @terdon, if they are modified it has to be done globally, which introduces some problems. And the new value has to be maintained and not reset when the system is rebooted.

Comment: Ah. OK, please [edit] your question and describe the limitations you need to deal with precisely. Perhaps you could set `/etc/profile` to read the variables from another file and make that file world-writeable.

Comment: I'll do my best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution might be to have these variables set in a file, making that file world-writeable and sourcing it from `/etc/bash.bashrc`. That way, the variables would be available to all users, any change in the sourced file would be kept after reboot and would also be available to any new shells started. Note that any open shells will not have their values updated.

1. Create the file with the variable definitions and make it world readable

   ```
   printf "%s=%s\n%s=%s\n" "var1='foo'" "var2='bar'" | sudo tee /etc/variables
   sudo chmod a+w /etc/variables
   ```

   That will create a file called `/etc/variables` with the following contents:

   ```
   var1='foo'
   var2='bar'
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/bash.bashrc` to make it source that file

   ```
   sudo printf "\n## Source global variables\n. /etc/variables\n" | 
       sudo tee -a /etc/bash.bashrc
   ```

Now, any changes in that file will be reflected in any new interactive non-login shells.

---

If you need this to be immediately inherited even by open shells, you could use bash's `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable:

```
   PROMPT_COMMAND
          If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each
          primary prompt.
```

Edit `/etc/profile` and add this line:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='. /etc/variables'
```

Once you have done this, any changes in the `/etc/variables` file will be immediately available to all shells since the file will be sourced before every prompt is shown. Note that this will only take effect after your users have logged back in since they will need to read `/etc/profile` again.

Comment: One last thing. When i use `export var1='test'` in a arbitrary user, the value is not set. Whys that? But i can read `foo` and `bar`

Comment: @javacake that won't work,  you can't export variables to another user's session.  If you want to add a new. Variable,  add it to the `/etc/variables` file.

Comment: But can i change the variables from any user or are they static in the variables file?

Comment: @JavaCake if you make the file editable by all users (either with `chmod a+w /etc/variables` or by creating a new user group for the target users and changing the ownership of the file to that group), then any of your users will be able to edit the file and the changes will be immediately available to any other user. Basically, that file is read before a [prompt](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_Unix/Explanations/Shell_Prompt) is shown so it is re-read after every command executed.

Comment: Im not sure if this will be a good solution after all. I will be changing the variables very often, and as i can understand it will require direct editing of the file. The modification of variables could e.g. be done within a nodejs application interacting via a web-interface. Perhaps the database solution would be better after all compared to file manipulation?

Comment: @JavaCake up to you. It would be trivial to have your node.js application edit the file though. You might want to come into our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux) room and discuss the relative merits. I'm usually there, feel free to ping me, but the other regulars will also be able to help. Many of them much more so than I.

Comment: Cool i'll try that!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22308/discussion-between-javacake-and-terdon).